# Excepcion en conexion JDBC Java a Derby: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

Quiero crear un programa que se conecte a una base de datos JDBC con Java. Tengo el método creado para la conexión de la base de datos:

```
 public void estableixConnexio() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    
    String urlBaseDades = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/BaseDatos2021";
    String usuari = "usuario";
    String contrasenya = "contraseña";
    try {
         Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlBaseDades , usuari, contrasenya);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        conn = null;
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Pero no hay forma de que funcione y me da la excecpcion de que no carga la clase:

```
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
```

En la pestaña de NEtbeans de Services si que se me conecta a la base de datos y puedo crear y modificar las tablas y los datos. Tambien desde terminal con el comando *ij* puedo conectarme a la base de datos y trabajar.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

intenta cambiando el driver en tu Class.forName `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` de igual forma te dejo una referencia para que te ayude un poco más (Click Aqui)[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html]

Comment: como verás la cadena de conexión es de derby, no de mysql